# Redux Tutorial - why can't or shouldn't the action creator dispatch actions?

Tags: redux

I am working my way through the redux tutorial [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html). I have some experience with "traditional Flux" so the first codeblock looks familiar to me, but I am confused by the second statement.

> In traditional Flux, action creators often trigger a dispatch when invoked, like so:
>
> `function addTodoWithDispatch(text) {
>     const action = {
>       type: ADD_TODO,
>       text
>     }
>     dispatch(action)
>   }`
>
> In Redux this is not the case.
>   Instead, to actually initiate a dispatch, pass the result to the dispatch() function:
>
> `dispatch(addTodo(text))
>   dispatch(completeTodo(index))`

If my action creator is this:

```
function addTodo(text) {
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO,
        text
    }
}

dispatch(addTodo(text))
```

Isn't that functionally equivalent to the first code example? Why does redux require the second way to actually dispatch?

Answer (score 2):

Action Creators are used in Redux for adding extra layers of indirection and abstraction.

There are several reasons to use action creators rather than putting all your logic directly:

Encapsulation: Consistently using action creators means that a component doesn't have to know any of the details of creating and dispatching the action.

Abstraction: Put the logic for creating that action in one place.

Brevity: There could be some larger logic that goes into preparing the action object, rather than just immediately returning it.

Testability: It is easy to write tests for the component that pass in a mock version of the function instead. It also enables reusing the component in another situation.

Useful resources:

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators

http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/

Comment: Hey, that looks _awfully_ similar to the reasons I wrote in my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Why Use Action Creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/) :)

Comment: @markerikson thanks for commenting I add your link resource and other useful to my answer.

Comment: I agree that action creators are much better than dispatching and defining the action directly in component code, but my question is more along the lines of: Why prefer `dispatch(addTodo(text))` over `addTodoWithDispatch(text)`?